# Nuxt.js Build Failed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

My Nuxt.js Code is running fine in dev mode but when I am trying to build the project getting this error every time. 
I am using Vue js with Nuxt and Vuetify for Styling.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[9364:000001CD3A848F50]    98564 ms: Mark-sweep 1266.3 (1441.0) -> 1253.3 (1441.5) MB, 982.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.236, current mu = 0.194) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[9364:000001CD3A848F50]    99810 ms: Mark-sweep 1268.5 (1441.5) -> 1255.2 (1441.5) MB, 942.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.240, current mu = 0.244) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0000029F089DC5C1]
Security context: 0x02528061e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: _addHashTableEntry$3 [0000029F613885B9] [C:\Users\Jahid\Documents\Vue Apps\foxvue\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:~22929] [pc=0000029F0A784FF3](this=0x03975ce20131 <JsLinkedHashMap map = 0000016E4169F479>,table=0x03975ce207d1 <Object map = 00000006753069D9>,key=0x02832ded6969 <String[23]: property-class-modifier>,value=1)
    2: putIfAbsent$2 [000002...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7CCE9DD8A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF7CCE78886 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF7CCE79200 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF7CD1930DE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7CD19300F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF7CD379804 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF7CD3707E6 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF7CD36EE3C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF7CD377B87 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF7CD377C06 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF7CD4A1CD8 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray+56
12: 00007FF7CD4A2652 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+66
13: 00007FF7CD223FB6 v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::AtPut+15542
14: 00007FF7CD21D7AD v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::SimpleNumberDictionary,v8::internal::SimpleNumberDictionaryShape>::KeyAt+7837
15: 00007FF7CD492822 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeManager::LookupCode+13426
16: 0000029F089DC5C1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! foxflue@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foxflue@1.0.0 generate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jahid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T15_21_51_902Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You have heap out of memory. You reached your memory limit

Comment: How can i fix it ?

Comment: well, you need more memory, that means you need more RAM. How much RAM do you have now? 4GB, 8GB? more? less?

Comment: Ram - 8 GigaByte

Comment: well i dont know... upgrade to 16gb or write more efficient code

Comment: The source of this error might not be your RAM size. Try running `nuxt generate` with `node --max-old-space-size=8192` by doing `node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/nuxt generate`. This will allow Nuxt to use all of your 8GB available memory. If this error still persists it means that your code is running in some kind of infinite loop which fills up the Javascript heap and you will have to share more of it so we can identify the source of the problem. 8GB of memory is more than enough to build a Nuxt app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem by Updating Node Js to the latest version. Before I was using Node Js 10.x.